# Halachic Right to Confront Accuser?

Tags: criminal-procedure, civil-procedure

Does halachah protect a right to confront one's accusers similar to the constitutional protection in the U.S. and other places?

Comment: Can you explain this right in more detail?

Comment: Both litigants need to be present in the room, but they each make their case to the dayanim -- not confront one another.

Comment: This is the type of thing I would expect to find in the writings of Menahem Elon or other writers of the Mishpat 'Ivri movement.

Comment: That rules seems to be the closest to an analog @Shalom

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to testify against yourself, or even for yourself, or plead guilty, or sign a confession. [Sanhedrin 9b-10a, Yevamot 25b] How would it help you to confront your accusers?

The judges just listen to the charges from the plaintiffs, examine the evidence, interrogate the witnesses, discuss the matter among themselves, and then reach a verdict by majority vote.